# c# epplus modify excel how count each column last cells number

Tags: c#, excel-2007, epplus

I want to add new data by Excel worksheet in C# EPPlus.but worksheet each cloumn last cell is different

this code show worksheet the longest column

```
worksheet.Dimension.Columns;
```

But,how can show each column last cell number

my code :

```
private void btn_open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets[3];

    int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;
    MessageBox.Show(colCount.ToString());
    Columnbase = IndexToColumn(worksheet.Dimension.Columns+1);
    Columnbase = Columnbase+"2";
    worksheet.Cells[Columnbase].Value = "12010";
}

static readonly string[] Columns = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ", "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AP", "AQ", "AR", "AS", "AT", "AU", "AV", "AW", "AX", "AY", "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BC", "BD", "BE", "BF", "BG", "BH" };

public static string IndexToColumn(int index)
{
    if (index <= 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("index must be a positive number");
    return Columns[index - 1];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "want to add new data by Excel worksheet" ? 
you want to pass through all cells in worksheet ?

Comment: i want to write the new data in excel worksheet cell,but each worksheet column last cell is different,how can i write

Comment: You mean that, you want to overwrite the existing data in a worksheet and you cannot specify the last column every worksheet ?

Comment: i mean worksheet each column last cells is different e.g fist row last cell is R2,second row last cell is T3

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to know about the `Cells` object in an `Worksheet` in EPPlus is that it contains only references to cell that have data added to it.  So with a little bit of `LINQ` you can get the address of every "Row" like this:

```
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
{
    var workbook = pck.Workbook;
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

    worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Test";
    worksheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Test";
    worksheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "Test";
    worksheet.Cells["D1"].Value = "Test";

    worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "Test";
    worksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = "Test";
    worksheet.Cells["C2"].Value = "Test";
    worksheet.Cells["D2"].Value = "Test";
    worksheet.Cells["E2"].Value = "Test";

    worksheet.Cells["A3"].Value = "Test";

    var lastRowCell1 = worksheet.Cells.Last(c => c.Start.Row == 1);
    Console.WriteLine(lastRowCell1.Address); //Prints "D1"

    var lastRowCell2 = worksheet.Cells.Last(c => c.Start.Row == 2);
    Console.WriteLine(lastRowCell2.Address); //Prints "E2"

    var lastColCell1 = worksheet.Cells.Last(c => c.Start.Column == 1);
    Console.WriteLine(lastColCell1.Address); //Prints "A3"

    var lastColCell2 = worksheet.Cells.Last(c => c.Start.Column == 2);
    Console.WriteLine(lastColCell2.Address); //Prints "B2"
}
```